# Rebuild or Reorganize indexes in Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, index, data-warehouse

My database is around 8 Tb and it has 34.ndf files & tables are portioned i'm using ola hallengren script for index maintenance but job is running for more than 2 days to finish the job. is there any other index maintenance script which can bring down maintenance time?

Comment: Do you actually need to rebuild/reorg the indexes? Often a statistics update will provide enough of a performance improvement.

Comment: Have a look at this one.  This might help.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164382/factors-to-consider-while-rebuild-reorganize-of-index-in-sql-server-2012/164390#164390

Answer (score 2):

You can consider to change the fillfactor of some of your indexes:

see [Specify Fill Factor for an Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index)

The fact is the solution you use is already optimized, it does not consider small indexes(having only few pages) and does not rebuild all of the indexes but only those that need to. Maybe you just use 100% FF everywhere and your keys are smth like guids?

I think this article can help youin it: [How to choose a good index fill factor](http://sqlmag.com/blog/how-choose-good-index-fill-factor)